# how to create dynamic text label autohotkey

Tags: dynamic, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a program that will show me in a text label, the color value of the x,y positions given in Edit fields.

The problem is that it will only work once and after it will not refresh. It is not a problem about the value itself since the value is correctly updated when I use a MsgBox.

See my following code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance, force

Gui, Add, Text,, X ;xpos label
Gui, Add, Edit, vxpos Number ;xpos to be entered by user
Gui, Add, Text,, Y ;ypos label
Gui, Add, Edit, vypos Number ;ypos to be entered by user
Gui, Add, Button, Default, GetColor ;to get the color
Gui, Add, Text,, vmyRGB ;color value that should be displayed
Gui, Show, AutoSize
Return

ButtonGetColor: ;called when pressing the button
    Gui, Submit, NoHide ;retrieves values of my edit fields
    PixelGetColor, myColor, %xpos%, %ypos% ;pixelcolor in my myColor variable
    GuiControl,, vmyRGB, %myColor% ;updates my text field with the variable value, working once
    MsgBox, %myColor% ;checks the value of my variable, always working
Return
```

Need some help on this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more research using different keywords, I found out a solution:

replacing

```
Gui, Add, Text,, vmyRGB ;color value that should be displayed
```

by

```
Gui, Add, Text, vmyRGB, %myRGB% ;color value that should be displayed
```

and replacing

```
GuiControl,, vmyRGB, %myColor% ;updates my text field with the variable value, working once
```

by

```
GuiControl, Text, myRGB, %myColor% ;updates my text field with the variable value
```

Comment: I guess that `%vmyRGB%` should be `%myRGB%`? the `v`  is only used for specifying the Variable option. See documentation for details

Comment: also, if your problem is solved, please mark this question right here as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes I solved my problem but I can't mark it as accepted before waiting 2 more days (maybe because it's my own answer or because my account is new I guess).
+ I don't know but why it worked even with %vmyRGB% instead of %myRGB%, I changed it tho.